# Biometrics Data Type in SQL

Tags: sql, biometrics, navision

I'm trying to insert biometrics templates into SQL Table, what should be the field data type to be used.

This template should be readable from Dynamic Nav 5.1 any idea how ?

Comment: depence on your biometric templates, raw data or characteristic? Last one are usually integer arrays.

Comment: blob? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd301120.aspx

Answer (score 2):

biometric templates are sent as binary data from the fingerprint or biometric sdk. Its a good idea to convert the templates to base64 before saving into the database. many people tried saving as binary but always had to deal with database migration as the binary is treated differently in each database products. Just save as base64 so you never have to worry about saving.